# windows phone 8.1 language selection Manually

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I Have 15 Language support on my application i want to switch between the 15 language manually without restart phone to take effect, Using combobox if I click Arabic or Russian switch the app UI Language.
[image]

Like TubeCast (YouTube Client For wp user )
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply `Localize` your app without any restart of the device. I learned it from [here](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/02/01/tips-for-localizing-windows-phone-8-xaml-apps-part1/), which ideally helped me too to come over this `Localization` concept.

[Sample](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/localizing-a-windows-phone-8-application--cms-22989)

Comment: Yes it's for WP8.0. Have a look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180245/class-library-localization-in-windows-universal-store-app